# Coalesce operator - usage (c#)

Tags: c#, coalesce

Ive seen an increasing number of pieces of code that use the coalesce operator in a (to me anyway) slightly odd manner, thoughts on this usage?

e.g. doing:

```
string foo = null;
void bar(){
 foo = foo??"hello";
}
```

instead of

```
string foo = null;
void bar(){
 if (foo==null)
  foo="hello";
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question that can have a definite answer?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that usage.

Comment: @Oded, The response with the most upvotes - democratic community standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an entirely reasonable use of the null coalescing operator to me. Note that it's not *quite* the same as the first code snippet, as it will be reassigning `foo` either way. This could be significant if you were actually using a *property* rather than a *variable* - the property setter would be invoked regardless of the current value.

Answer (score 1):

It makes code shorter and more readable while providing the vitual functionality of checking on null objects.

Answer (score 0):

The main differentiating factor is that `??` is an operator and can therefore be used in other expressions. As to where to use it -- it's completely up to developer.

Answer (score 0):

An Amazing situation where Coalesce Operator may be helpful. Thanks to Eric. 
[Please follow the link and Eric's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399091/returning-the-first-method-that-works-more-elegant-way/5399145#5399145)